# Is the period of one muhurta fixed, and what is the ghatika which is mentioned in panchanga?

Tags: time, terminology, calendar, muhurta

Muhurta is considered approximately 48 minutes.

But it is determined as 1/30  of the day, so if the length of the day is changing will the period of muhurta also change?

Also, panchanga mentions ghati phala. If it says a tithi is from this ghatika, then what is the reference point?

Comment: Day = 24 hours or 1440 minutes. 1/30 of 1440 means 48 minutes for a muhurta. Day is always 24 hours, so no change in duration of muhurta. Ghatika is half a muhurta or 24 minutes. Reference point is sunrise.

Comment: But sunrise to sunrise .. the time changes right ? as far as i know our day starts from sunrise to the next sunrise. if that is the case then the duration changes right

Comment: Yes you are correct. I don’t know about this.